# JSON refactoring (merging content) with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Could you please point me some directions how to sort this with javascript (can be jQuery):

```
"A1" : { "value" : "No data", "href" : "/A1", "tooltip" : {"content" : "A1 No data"} },
    "A2" : { "value" : "1111", "href" : "/A2", "tooltip" : {"content" : "A2 1111 (2013)"} },
    "B1" : { "value" : "2222", "href" : "/B1", "tooltip" : {"content" : "B1 2222 (2010)"} },
    "B1" : { "value" : "3333", "href" : "/B1", "tooltip" : {"content" : "B1 3333 (2009)"} },
```

I would like to achieve somethink like:

```
"B1" : { 
        "value" : {"y2009" : "3333", "y2010" : "2222"},
        "href" : "/B1", 
        "tooltip" : {
            "y2009" : {"content" : "B1 3333 (2009)"},
            "y2010" : {"content" : "B1 2222 (2010)"} 
         } 
    }
```

Comment: If the original data is JSON, you will have problems parsing this from the start, because the second "B1" value will overwrite the first and you won't be able to access it at all.How do you get the data in the first place?

Comment: Ya, this isn't really valid object...

Comment: imagine it like: data given : {A1:{},A2:{},B1:{},B1{}}
I can access both B1s before any overwriting happens

Comment: I have the data (like the first snippet) in a variable I can access.

Comment: @damonteo The only way is if it is a string, not an object. But then, you still couldn't easily parse it. Could you just provide any relevant code or example like a jsFiddle? And anyway, this is really bad idea to store data like this. Whatever return it in this format, shoud then be changed

Comment: yeah thats the thing I dont have anything relevant just this (and this is what I get..). dealing with it as a string is my only idea as well unfortunately..

Comment: Or... get the source fixed. that's completely invalid json, you shouldn't have to work with that, pretty much every major language has a JSON serializer accessible either built-in or as a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, your data is an array with objects, like below, the you could iterate over and assign all elements to a new object structure

```js
var array = [{ "A1": { "value": "No data", "href": "/A1", "tooltip": { "content": "A1 No data" } } }, { "A2": { "value": "1111", "href": "/A2", "tooltip": { "content": "A2 1111 (2013)" } } }, { "B1": { "value": "2222", "href": "/B1", "tooltip": { "content": "B1 2222 (2010)" } } }, { "B1": { "value": "3333", "href": "/B1", "tooltip": { "content": "B1 3333 (2009)" } } }],
    object = {};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = Object.keys(a)[0],
        year = (/(?:\()(\d{4})(?:\))/.exec(a[key].tooltip.content) || [, 'No data'])[1];

    if (!(key in object)) {
        object[key] = { "value": {}, "href": a[key].href, "tooltip": {} };
    }            
    object[key].value[year] = a[key].value;
    object[key].tooltip[year] = a[key].tooltip.content;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort writing this down :) seems like a feasible way sorting it. thx again

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira, i wrapped the two properties in own object in the array, please see above.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments, you'll suffer a lot if you can't change your received data to remove those duplicates properties. **Giving a call to your server guy is probably your best option**.

However, if he is particularly stubborn, or if he is your boss, or if he left the company 20 years ago with the only copy of the server source code, you could grab [this](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) (out of the good old times where all browsers didn't implement natively JSON.parse) and fork it.

First, this will give you an idea of the complexity of JSON parsing and if you fork it successfully, provide you a nice solution.

I would start by the walk function line 427:

```
function walk(holder, key) {

// The walk method is used to recursively walk the resulting structure so
// that modifications can be made.
```

good luck with that :)